# SQL: Get most recent maximum entry

Tags: mysql, groupwise-maximum

Anyone know how to get the most RECENT, maximum score from this table:

```
----------------------------------------
|id |game_id |level |score |date       |
----------------------------------------
|1  |0       |1     |90    |1391989720 |
|1  |0       |1     |95    |1391989721 |
|1  |0       |1     |95    |1391989722 |
|1  |1       |1     |4     |1391989723 |
|1  |1       |1     |8     |1391989724 |
|1  |1       |2     |6     |1391989725 |
----------------------------------------
```

So far I have this:

```
SELECT progress_max.game_id, 
       progress_max.level, 
       progress_max.date AS max_date,              
       max_score 
FROM 
(
    SELECT game_id, level, MAX(score) AS max_score
    FROM cdu_user_progress 
    WHERE lesson_id = 1 
    GROUP BY game_id, level 
) AS ms 
JOIN cdu_user_progress progress_max ON progress_max.game_id = ms.game_id AND progress_max.level = ms.level AND progress_max.score = ms.max_score 
WHERE progress_max.lesson_id = 1 
GROUP BY game_id, level
```

But that only gets me the FIRST maximum score (date 1391989721)...

Comment: What results are you trying to get?  Most recent maximum = ?

Comment: Most recent maximum is date 1391989722 (score = 95)

Comment: Do you want it per game and level?  Or just one row result from the table?

Comment: Yes, per game and level...

Comment: Your question is not clear about what id stands for and how it should be treated.

Comment: This question is asked more or less EVERY SINGLE DAY in SO. It's also correctly answered nearly as often. Not today... so far.

Comment: Of course, any solution would normally be dependent upon the existence of a PRIMARY KEY!

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler solution using `order by` to get the best latest score :

```
select game_id, level, score, date 
from cdu_user_progress
where id = 1
order by score desc, date desc
limit 1
```

To get all the best scores and their latest time you need a join.

```
select a.game_id, a.level, a.score, max(p.date) 
from (select game_id, level, max(score) as score
from cdu_user_progress
group by game_id, level) as a
inner join cdu_user_progress p
on a.game_id = p.game_id, a.level = p.level, a.score = p.score
group by a.game_id, a.level, a.score
```

Actually, since your question is not clear enough, I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: But that doesn't group by game and level?

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question.

Comment: Lorenz, I dv'd you, but I think your edit's OK really (at least, on the basis of the information provided so far). Edit it again somehow and I'll give you your vote back!